# In jQuery how do I add a value for number of decimal places?

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I am checking for valid input and successfully checked for blank inputs, but how do I check for valid lengths in decimal places using jquery?

```
 if ($val === "")
```

This is fine for blank values, but what is the correct syntax that finds an input no greater than 2 decimal places?

This is the code so far and the browser is now reverting to the native browser pop-ups for warning on input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkVelocity").each(function() {
      $val = $(this).val();
      if ($val === "") {
        if ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) {
        $(this).popover({
          placement: "left",
           content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
          template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>'+
              '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" id="invalid-input3">'+
              '</i></div><div class="popover-content col-9">Enter the velocity of the car between 10 and 300 ms<sup>-1</sup>, kmh<sup>-1</sup> or mph.'+
              '</div></div>' 
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
      }}
    })
  })
})
```

Originally it is working for blank or incorrect non-number inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkVelocity").each(function() {
      $val = $(this).val();
      if ($val === "") {       
        $(this).popover({
          placement: "left",
           content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
          template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>'+
              '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" id="invalid-input3">'+
              '</i></div><div class="popover-content col-9">Enter the velocity of the car between 10 and 300 ms<sup>-1</sup>, kmh<sup>-1</sup> or mph.'+
              '</div></div>' 
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

But it does not work for when decimal places exceed 2 for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake in the question, it is meant to say no greater than 2 dp. 

So I don't mind 2, 2.2 or 2.21 but not 2.201 (trailing zeroes aren't significant in jquery so they do not count anyway, you could write 2.00000000000000000 but it is just going to read as 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that trailing zeroes should be allowed, which the previous answers don't (they'll reject `"2.000"`). *(It wasn't clear early on that you wanted to do that, so far enough. :-) )*

I think I'd lean toward a regular expression approach:

```
const rex = /^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/;
const valid = rex.test($val);
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/;
function test($val, expect) {
  const valid = rex.test($val);
  const validmsg = valid ? "valid" : "INVALID";
  const success = !valid === !expect;
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify($val)}: ${validmsg} ${success ? "OK" : "<=== ERROR"}`);
}
// Good ones
test("2", true);
test("2.1", true);
test("2.12", true);
test("2.120", true);
test("2.120000", true); // Trailing zeros okay
// Bad ones
test("", false);
test("2.123", false);
test("2.120001", false);
```

The regular expression `/^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/` says:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - allow zero or more whitespace chars (you may want to leave this out and trim the string first instead)
- `(?:\d+|0)` - a non-capturing group defining an *alternation* (multiple alternatives) that will match either `\d+` (one or more digits) or `0` (literally)
- `(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)` - a non-capturing group defining

  - `\.` - a literal `.` for the decimal place
  - `\d{0,2}` - zero, one, or two digits
  - `0*` - any number of `0` characters
- `?` - makes the entire non-capturing group in front of it optional, in case there's no decimal part at all
- `\s*` - allow zero or more whitespace chars (you may want to leave this out and trim the string first instead)
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I thought that jquery just allowed trailing zeros and ignored them as not significant. I ran a couple of experiments and it didn't matter if I had one decimal place or 20 and they were all zeros, it didn't throw an "invalid" out come.

Comment: @PaulDavis - jQuery has nothing to do with this. By the time you have `$val`, you're just using JavaScript native objects and functions, not ones supplied by jQuery. Since it's a *string*, `"2"`, `"2.0"`, `"2.00"`, etc. are all different. An approach naively counting the characters after the `.` will fail to allow trailing zeroes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi T.J. While your solution seems to be the best answer, instead of naively doing the `.length` on the string split, couldn't this be viabale? `(parseFloat($val).toString().split('.')[1] || "").length;` Using `parseFloat` will remove the trailing zeroes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did try the code, like this: https://gyazo.com/064a59d9f2b771b2393f25b6129be51f

(sorry, did it as a gif, woops) but it doesn't work as anticipated. So maybe I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: This was me trying multiple zeroes and ending up with the popover firing. https://gyazo.com/6e1c7a471c6e8acfc0abfaf44e1754ab

It's a shame that I am doing this wrong somehow. Looks awesome otherwise!

Comment: @RyanWilson - In that code you're trying to use a `length` property on a number. :-) But if you put `String` at the beginning you'd be parsing the number, then converting it back to a string in standard form: `String(parseFloat($val).toString().split('.')[1] || "").length` That might work depending on the OP's needs. It's good enough for most people most of the time. But it's a bit fragile because the standard string form of a number isn't always what you might expect -- it varies depending on the value of the number. Consider the similar-looking numbers `0.0000001` and `1.0000001`. Same ...

Comment: ...number of decimal places, it's just that one has `0` as its whole part and the other has `1` as its whole part. But `String(parseFloat("0.0000001"))` is `"1e-7"` while `String(parseFloat("1.0000001"))` is `"1.0000001"`. There are other ways to get surprising results from converting to number and back to string. For instance, `String(parseFloat("0.29999999999999998"))` is `"0.3"`. The reason for **that** is that the number-to-string algorithm is much, much more complex that one might expect -- there are even academic research papers written on it (including ones ...

Comment: ...[linked from the JavaScript specfication](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring) -- scroll down to "Note 3". Isn't IEEE-754 floating point such ***fun***! :-) But again, none of that is meant in any way to bash that solution, which would be good enough for most people in most situations. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like what you have to say. It makes sense. If we are going to code something, we should be coding it to account for the use cases as best we can. I appreciate your time and effort in what you have shown me today. Thanks again. Can you explain why I would need the `String` in front of my code, I ran it with your way and with my way in fiddle and  console and I see no difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `parseFloat($val).toString().split('.')[1]` produces a string already by calling `.toString()` or if in the case of `2.0000` it returns undefined like you showed me earlier and defaults to empty.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No worries. Thanks again for everything! :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is great stuff. I am super surprised at how complex it is to just find a non zero multiple zero decimal place. So, I am wondering if you can look at what was proposed above and how should I fix it?

I've written:

` const rex = /^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/;  ` 

And then: ` if (rex.test($val)) { ` 

But this fails to stop the pop-up firing if someone writes a correct number but to many zeroes in decimal places. So the calculation goes ahead, but the popover warning still fires.

Answer (score 3):

To check for decimal places, do a split on period and get the length of the second element in the array. Since the question has been clarified to say that something like 2.000 or 2.210000000 should also be accepted, you could use a combination of `.parseFloat()` and `.toString()` with `.length` to allow the passage of strings like 2.0000000 or 2.22000000:

```
if($val !== "" && $val.indexOf('.') > -1){
   //We have decimal places, use combination of 
   //parseFloat toString length
   //parseFloat will remove trailing zeroes.
   const decimalLength = (parseFloat($val).toString().split('.')[1] || "").length;
    
   //This doesn't work as it will block on trailing zeroes, ie. 2.000000 or 2.0100000
   //const decimalLength = $val.split('.')[1].length;

   if(decimalLength > 2) {
       //Do something
   }
}
```

Or you can go with a more lean approach suggested by T.J. Crowder:

```
if (($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) { /* Disallow that many decimal places */ }
```

Comment: Or just: `if (($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) { /* Disallow that many decimal places */ }`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting. I figured that trying to split on an empty string and indexing on that failed split would throw an exception, not produce undefined. I put your suggestion in the answer and credited you with it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, giving that a try.

Comment: Ug, it probably does work... but for me it seems to prevent the function from operating. 

The if($val === "") works, but as soon as I add to it, the function stops :(

Comment: @PaulDavis Not sure what you mean by your comment. Update your post with your modified code and show where you are getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this... honestly, I have been stuck for days on this.

Comment: Also, forgive my noobiness, it really is a new world for me... I'm only a couple of weeks into JS.

Comment: @PaulDavis Empty string will not evaluate to greater than 2, so it's skipping the code block in your original code. Please join me in a discussion and I'll show you what you need to change.

Comment: @RyanWilson - `anystring.split(".")[1]` will never throw an error, you'd only get an error if you were trying to call `split` on something that isn't a string (`undefined`, for instance). FWIW: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/t6sfqpch/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I tested it out in my console. I just never knew it evaluated that way. I appreciate your fiddle and the insight. I'll file that one away for future use.

Comment: @RyanWilson not sure how to join you in a chat... would love to and I would be so grateful too!

Comment: @PaulDavis I don't think I can invite you to chat. I tried and it gives me an error. So if you're value is empty string or less than 3 decimal places, you want it to execute the code in your original block which only checked for empty string correct?

Comment: If the value is an empty string or more than 2 decimal places. 

So "" would be invalid as would 2.456 would be invalid.

Comment: @PaulDavis Then in your original code above replace this line `if ($val === "") {` with this: `if ($val === "" || ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) {`, please also check with T.J. as he may have pointed out another case which this doesn't account for, example "2.000" failing .

Comment: It seems to work. Now I just need the popover to disappear when they back space to the appropriate amount of decimal places. 

https://gyazo.com/d35eea776d5ad176315f380d85d6e19c

Comment: @PaulDavis You're screen grab looks like it removes the error message once you reduce it to two decimal places, it just looks like it may be delayed by a few milliseconds. I think you should look at T.J.'s posted answer, if you need to allow for multiple trailing `zeroes`

Comment: It doesn't.. I had to click to remove it. But that's ok, I have changed how that is called now. But, I have decided (oh, I am so sorry) that I need the jquery argument to ignore decimal places if they are all zeroes. 

So 2.20 is as good as 2.20000000000000000000 (it just needs to ignore all that!)

Comment: @PaulDavis Then you probably want to work with T.J., his regex will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: So, to put that in the line you just made... how is that going to look?

Comment: @PaulDavis You would declare this `const rex = /^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/;` before your `if statement`, then replace `if ($val === "")` with `if (rex.test($val))` in your original post. Please give credit to T.J. if you use his answer.

Comment: It still pops up with that - but it is very awesome. But we haven't beaten the pop up completely yet :)

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is to use regex pattern to do this validation:

```js
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;

// returns true if valid the param has 0,1,2 decimal points, otherwise returns false
function validateDecimalPoint(param) {

  console.log(regex.test(param));

  return regex.test(param);
}


validateDecimalPoint('2.12');
```

Comment: I wanted to learn how to use regex - I tried the other day, but it got painful. I'll return to that again some day I think.

Comment: I would strongly suggest u to take a deep dive into it. And the best place to do it is the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions 

Also, it's very useful to practice with them a bit using online regex testers. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/03af82a5e3018cfdf59ebda640003024

Actually, it might just be HTML doing that not jQuery.. but either way it ignores all the zeroes even though I have a max of a step 0.01 on this.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by this code:

```
const isOpen = (val) => {
  const num = parseFloat(val);
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    const decimals = num.toString().split('.')[1] || '';
    if (decimals.length > 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkLength").each(function() {
      const val = $(this).val();
      if (isOpen(val)) {
        $(this).popover({
          html: true,
          placement: "bottom",
          content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
          template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
            '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" id="invalid-input7">' +
            '</i></div><div class="popover-content col-9">Enter a value between 2 and 50 m with up to 2 decimal places.' +
            '</div></div>'
        });
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).popover("hide");
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

In short: The popover will only fire for empty strings, numbers that are too high, numbers that are too low or numbers that have too many decimal places.

Conversely, the popover will not fire for correct values, whole numbers, or decimal places that do not exceed the maximum value (2) or are decimal places with only zeroes in them.